# Kotlin written library to share entities loses information about default values when included in another project

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, gradle

I have a Kotlin Spring project that contains simple `Entity` models. I am publishing this library to my local maven (and Github packages) so I can reuse them in my other projects.

However something is not working properly when I include the library in another project.

Here is the original `Attachment.kt` entity class

```kotlin
@Entity
class Attachment(
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null,
    var url: String? = "",
    @OneToOne
    var author: UserInfo?,
    var fileSize: Long? = 0,
    var fileName: String? = "",
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    var createdAt: DateTime? = DateTime.now()
)
```

As you can see there are default values.
Now when I include the library that contains `Attachment.kt` the constructor is giving me an error since it's expecting values. This should not happen since there are default values present.

When I checked the "sources" of the included entity library I can see the following:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity public open class Attachment public constructor(id: kotlin.Long? /* = compiled code */, url: kotlin.String? /* = compiled code */, author: com.imhotep.shared.entity.UserInfo?, fileSize: kotlin.Long? /* = compiled code */, fileName: kotlin.String? /* = compiled code */, createdAt: org.joda.time.DateTime? /* = compiled code */) {
    @field:javax.persistence.OneToOne public open var author: com.imhotep.shared.entity.UserInfo? /* compiled code */

    @field:org.hibernate.annotations.Type public open var createdAt: org.joda.time.DateTime? /* compiled code */

    public open var fileName: kotlin.String? /* compiled code */

    public open var fileSize: kotlin.Long? /* compiled code */

    @field:javax.persistence.Id @field:javax.persistence.GeneratedValue public open var id: kotlin.Long? /* compiled code */

    public open var url: kotlin.String? /* compiled code */
}
```

Since Java does not have default values I understand why the library has problems here. But how can I manage to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Add [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation) annotation to your `Attachment` class.

Comment: unfortunately it did not help